# get characters (not separated with spaces) in array using scanf()

Tags: c++, c, scanf

I need to store characters from user's input in  array, BUT not one by one. User will input them as one line like this;

```
....
```

I need to save each dot in array, but I can't do this:

```
scanf("%s%s%s%s", &s[0], &s[1], &s[2], &s[3])
```

because user can enter N number of dots. So it must be dynamic, I guess.

Comment: Did you try `"%c%c%c%c"` as format string instead? Or use [`std::istream::get()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) in a loop. Also I don't see why you can't simply use `std::getline()`?

Comment: Do you only want to read dots? If so read the whole string using getline() into a std::string. You now have an array of characters.

Answer (score 4):

`scanf()` is a C runtime function.  In C++, you should be using [`std::cin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin) instead.  For instance, with [`std::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).  You can treat the returned [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) like an array of characters.

Answer (score 1):

> User will input them as one line like this; `....` I need to save each dot in array,

C solution:

Define upper sane bound like 1000 and use a *scanset* `"%[]"`.

```
// Read up to 1000 `.`
char dot[1000 + 1];
if (scanf(" %1000[.]") == 1) {
  //  Success
  puts(dot);
}
```

Additional code needed if other non-`.`, non -white-space characters need to be handled.